# Trying to create computed field in Hasura with a custom function

Tags: sql, postgresql, graphql, hasura

I'm trying to use [Hasura Computed Fields](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/schema/computed-fields.html#scalar-computed-fields) with a table called players to combine firstName and lastName columns. Below is me copying and altering the example shown in the documentation.

```
CREATE FUNCTION player_full_name(player_row players)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    SELECT player_row.firstName || ' ' || player_row.lastName
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Returns the following error:

```
SQL Execution Failed
postgres-error : missing FROM-clause entry for table "player_row"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a quick aside, it may not be directly related to your question, but with postgres, anytime you have column names, if there is any capitalization it requires you quote your fields, so in this case you would need the following function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION player_full_name(player_row players)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    SELECT player_row."firstName" || ' ' || player_row."lastName"
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Note the double quotes around the column names, postgres automatically lowercases all columns, i believe this is why hasura opts for snake case on their examples.

Also i noticed you referenced in your function `player_row players`, make sure the `players` portion at the end matches the exact name of your table.

Comment: That was it! The quotations are needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are your columns named `firstName` and `lastName`?

With `first_name` and `last_name` as columns in the `players` table, I was able to reproduce the error w/the function shared.

I believe your options are to rename the columns first_name --> firstName, and last_name --> lastName or define the full name function as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION player_full_name(player_row players)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    SELECT player_row.first_name || ' ' || player_row.last_name
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Comment: My columns are named firstName and lastName.